# Stack overflow error when attempting to print out LinkedList of integers recursively? (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, printing, stack-overflow

Working through a problem where I made two methods, iterative and recursive, for going through a Linked List then comparing how long it took for each to complete.

I'm trying to print an Linked List of that contains as many random integers (From 0-99) in a specified range (from 0-1000000) but I get a Stack Overflow error when I attempt to use my printRecursively function to print out the numbers of the list recursively. My iterative one works fine but I can't figure out why I keep getting a Stack Overflow error when I use my other method. Help? Thank you

```
public class Compare {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of integers you wish to have inside the LinkedList:");
    Integer numberOfItems = input.nextInt();
    while (numberOfItems > 1000000 || numberOfItems < 0){
        System.out.println("Not valid number. Please re-enter a valid integer:");
        numberOfItems = input.nextInt();
    }

    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    int i = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(i < numberOfItems){
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(99);
    list.add(i, randomNumber);
    i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to print iteratively or recursively? (Type i or r):");
    char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
    if (choice != 'i' && choice != 'r')
    {        
        int h = 0;
        while(h == 0){ 
        System.out.println("Incorrect input. (Type i or r):");
        choice = input.next().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'i' || choice == 'r'){
            h = 1;               
        }
        }
    }     

    if (choice == 'i'){
        double startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Functions blah = new Functions();
        blah.printIteratively(list);
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double duration = ((endTime - startTime)/1000000000);
        System.out.println("The method took " + duration + " seconds to complete.");
        }

    if (choice == 'r'){
        double startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Functions blah = new Functions();       
        blah.printRecursively(list);
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double duration = ((endTime - startTime)/1000000000);
        System.out.println("The method took " + duration + " seconds to complete.");
        } 
    }

}
```

And here's my functions:

```
public void printIteratively(LinkedList<Integer> list)
{  
     int k = list.size();
     for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
        System.out.println(list.get(j));
    }
}
public void printRecursively(LinkedList<Integer> list)
{
    while(!(list.peek() == null)){  
    System.out.println(list.pollLast());
    printRecursively(list);
     }
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do an iterative algorithm recursively?  That's just plain wrong and fails (as you have found out) when the list gets too big.  Doing it recursively is a waste of memory.  Just because you have a tool (recursion) does not mean it's appropriate for every task.  You wouldn't use a chisel as a screwdriver, or a screwdriver to carve wood.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm going through problems in my JAVA book and this was one of them. I don't really have a grasp on recursive functions yet so I thought it'd be helpful to try it out

Comment: OK, I applaud you for experimenting.  Learning the applications of algorithms is a cornerstone of computer science, and this was probably a good way to see the effect of applying recursion where iteration is a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that recursion is the wrong tool to use for iterating over the contents of a list.  That is an iterative sequential algorithm and recursion will fail when the list gets too big.  It's not a question of adjusting the recursive algorithm, it's just wrong and will *always* fail for a large enough list, where simple iteration would continue to work just fine.

The specific reason recursion fails is that each recursive call consumes a stack frame's worth of memory, which includes some housekeeping information and instances of all local variables in the method.  Eventually you run out of stack space, which results in a StackOverflow exception.

The recursive solution will always have an upper limit to the size of list it can handle which will almost surely be a lot smaller than the size of list you can store in memory.  You can increase the limit by allocating more stack space (using the `-Xss` command line option), but the limit is fundamentally part of the algorithm and the way recursion works in languages like Java.

If you are interested, look up the term "tail recursion". There are *some* languages where the compiler (or interpreter) will detect this and convert it to iteration (I think Lisp does this).

Comment: Thank you. So is there a way to curate this except to use a smaller LinkedList of numbers?

Comment: I think an important thing to note here is that while recursion is not the best choice for this particular case, it is still a very valuable tool from time to time, even in Java. When to use iteration and when to use recursion should be considered on a case-by-case basis, but deep recursion is just generally risky business in Java.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Makes sense. I'm just confused as to why my book would give me a problem with a limit of 1,000,000 spaces for creating a LinkedList if I was bound to meet Stack Overflow errors.

Comment: Maybe so you'd find out "the hard way" that recursion is inappropriate for that task?  Does the book discuss when recursion is appropriate?